# Regex (with lookaround) optimization

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to pull out entities from text, and would like to have a simple mechanism (until we deploy an NLP solution) to avoid negation. e.g: 
I'd like to find

> Patient has a history of Cynicisimitis

But avoid

> No history of Cynicisimitis

and also avoid

> Family history of Cynicisimitis

To that end I am using multiple lookbehinds to make my regex look like this:

```
((?<!(?i)no.{1,25}|denies.{1,35}|family.{1,35}|father.{1,10}|mother.{1,10})(?-i)${stringToMatch})
```

I tried adding \b to the negative lookbehind, thinking this will reduce the entry points the processor will have, but this actually made performance even worse.

Problem is - this appears to be performing very badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

- using `\b` to avoid false matches (in particular with the word "no")
- removing the useless `(?-i)` (an inline modifier applies only to the group where it is.)
- factorizing when it is possible to reduce the performance impact of `.{m,n}`

You obtain:

`(?<!(?i)\b(?:no\b.{1,25}|(?:denies|family)\b.{1,35}|(?:fa|mo)ther\b.{1,10})\b)history of Cynicisimitis\b`

What you can try:

- using lazy quantifiers instead of greedy quantifiers: `\bno\b.{1,25}?`
- putting the lookbehind after the stringToMatch:

  `\bhistory of Cynicisimitis\b(?<!(?i)\b(?:no\b.{1,25}|(?:denies|family)\b.{1,35}|(?:fa|mo)ther\b.{1,10})\bhistory of Cynicisimitis)`
- using a basic string search (that is from far faster than a regex) to find the offsets of stringToMatch, extract substrings from `offset-50` to `offset+stringToMatch.length+1` and only after test your pattern on substrings.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I'm trying it. Will update soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading Casimir(.*)'s answer, I ended up with this regexp -

```
(?<!(?i)\\bno\\b.{1,40})(?<!(?i)denie[sd].{1,50})(?<!(?i)family.{1,40})(?<!(?:(?i)fa|mo)ther.{1,20})(?<!(?:(?i)fr|m|p)aternal.{1,20})(${stringToMatch})"
```

Basically, I broke the single, long negative look around into several negative look behinds.
This is the step that increased performance the most ~ 30% faster processing.

I will update if I make any more progress.